# API - Successive calls

Tags: rest, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm working on an API (with Symfony) and I have a question for you :

- I have a method to create something (let's take a car for example)
- I have another method to create something else (let's take a boat for example)
- Now in my first method (create a car), I have a parameter that will create a boat too (after I created a car)

What is the best practice ?

- Make an observer ? Will it calls the second method or just do some code on his side (kind of duplicate code)
- Duplicate the code of the second method (I think that would be very bad) ?
- Call the second function (but it's an API is it really a good practice) ?

I'm impatient to read your thoughts about it, thanks in advance :) !

Jérémy

Comment: Maybe, you are looking for something like the [EventDispatcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html)?